# Валидация input file

Tags: html, jquery, файлы, form, input

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать валидацию для input file такого рода:

- Загрузка определённых расширений файлов (jpg,pdf,zip)
- Ограничение веса файла (до 2 мб)
- Ограничение количества файлов отправки (до 10 файлов)
- Вывод ошибки если она есть (по пунктам сверху)
- Если все файлы загружены (Вывод в теге "p" "Файлы загружены")

Возможно ли реализовать это на jquery.validate, просто нашёл там только accept на файл и ограничение размера файла. Подскажите пожалуйста какой плагин можно использовать или может у кого то есть готова валидация?

Comment: Такие проверки оптимальнее делать через `PHP` (первые 3 пункта) т.е вы можете загрузить файлы через  `AJAX` на сервеной части сделать все проверки и после вернуть ответ(последние два пункта)

Comment: @Arsen, подскажите как можно добавить класс к div через php?

Comment: Через переменную -  `$class_name = 'vash_class';  <div class="<?php echo $class_name;?>"></div>`